# Installing Electron on Windows 10 (`node-gyp rebuild` error)

Tags: python-2.7, npm, electron, node-gyp

I've seen a lot of Stack posts and GitHub posts on this, but I've hit a dead end and I'm not sure where else to turn (apologies if duplicate).

I'm following a guide [here](https://www.fyears.org/2017/02/electron-as-gui-of-python-apps-updated.html) to install Electron. On the command `npm install --runtime=electron --target=1.4.15`, I hit the common stack:

```
> msgpack@1.0.2 install D:\Research Documents\Fall 2017 - Work\Lab Work\sample_app\node_modules\msgpack
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\Research Documents\Fall 2017 - Work\Lab Work\sample_app\node_modules\msgpack>if not defined npm_config_n
ode_gyp (node "C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp
\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: 404 response downloading https://iojs.org/download/release/v1.4.15/iojs-v1.4.15.tar.gz
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node
-gyp\lib\install.js:210:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Request.onRequestResponse (C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_module
s\request\request.js:1074:10)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:473:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:362:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\User Name\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\n
pm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Research Documents\Fall 2017 - Work\Lab Work\sample_app\node_modules\msgpack
gyp ERR! node -v v6.10.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN gnomics@ No description
npm WARN gnomics@ No repository field.
npm WARN gnomics@ No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! msgpack@1.0.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the msgpack@1.0.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-09-25T04_40_03_337Z-debug.log
```

The guide suggests building from the source by running `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`, which runs successfully, but even after clearing the cache, the Electron install command still produces the same error.

I have Python2.7 in my PATH variable and PYTHON variable, as suggested by some Stack answers.

Funny enough, running `npm config -g set msvs_version 2015` followed by `npm i` worked. Then running the Electron install command seemed to work, until I ran the test `./node_modules/.bin/electron`, which produced:

```
D:\Research Documents\Fall 2017 - Work\Lab Work\sample_app\node_modules\electron\index.js:9
  throw new Error('Electron failed to install correctly, please delete node_modules/electron and try installing again')
  ^

Error: Electron failed to install correctly, please delete node_modules/electron and try installing again
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Research Documents\Fall 2017 - Work\Lab Work\sample_app\node_modules\electron
\index.js:9:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Research Documents\Fall 2017 - Work\Lab Work\sample_app\node_modules\electron
\cli.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

This is all being run on a x64 Windows 10 system. I've tried everything above on Windows PowerShell (as admin and not as admin), on command prompt (as admin and not as admin), and on Git Bash, all with the same error messages.

Any help would be much appreciated! (If any additional info is needed, such as Microsoft Visual Studio, SDK, or other installs, please let me know which ones and I'll updated accordingly).

EDIT 1: Just of note, running everything as a single command, i.e. `npm install --global --production --runtime=electron --target=1.4.15 --build-from-source windows-build-tools` also doesn't work (well the install completes without error, but Electron still says that it failed to install correctly).

UPDATE 1: Okay, so I deleted everything and cleared the cache and then I ran `npm config -g set msvs_version 2015`, followed by `npm i`, and then `npm install --runtime=electron --target=1.4.15`. Next I ran `./node_modules/.bin/electron` which worked. But then, launching the actual project created a new Electron error... So I don't think I "solved" anything really. The new error was:

```
D:\Research Documents\Fall 2017 - Work\Lab Work\sample_app\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:83 Uncaught Error: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
\\?\D:\Research Documents\Fall 2017 - Work\Lab Work\sample_app\node_modules\zmq\build\Release\zmq.node
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:598:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at bindings (D:\Research Documents\Fall 2017 - Work\Lab Work\sample_app\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Research Documents\Fall 2017 - Work\Lab Work\sample_app\node_modules\zmq\lib\index.js:6:30)
```